# Dicey dice four times

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction

There is a 6-sided die with **6 different** positive integer numbers on it. The die is rolled four times and it is guaranteed that the multiplication of these four numbers ($O_1 \times O_2\times O_3 \times O_4$) is divisible by the sum of the numbers ($D_1+D_2+D_3+D_4+D_5+D_6$) on the die.

What is the minimum value of the sum of the numbers on the die?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The minimal value of the sum $D_1+D_2+D_3+D_4+D_5+D_6$ is

> $81$.

**Proof**

First, note that

> the product of the $O_j$ must be divisible by $\sum D_i$ even if $O_j=\min_i(D_i)$ for all $j$.

- Clearly, then, $\min_i(D_i)$ can't be $1$ or $2$, since $1$ and $16$ can't be multiples of any sum of six distinct natural numbers.
- So let's try $\min_i(D_i)=3$. Then $\sum D_i$ must be a factor of $81$, and therefore a power of $3$ (and clearly not $3^0=1$), which means every $D_j$ has to be a multiple of $3$, so $\sum D_i=81=3\times27$.

This is achievable with e.g.

> $\{D_i\}_i=\{3,6,9,12,15,36\}$. Clearly any product of four of these will be a multiple of $81$, which is their sum.

Comment: "... therefore all Di are multiples of 6". I don't see how this follows, can you elaborate?

Comment: @ffao All fixed.

Comment: A simpler argument is that $3+4+5+6+7+8>27$, leaving $81$ as the only possibility for the sum. Though you'd still need your argument to construct a working example.